# Series basic question

Tags: analysis

$$\sum^N_{n=1}\liminf_{k \to \infty} f_k(n) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \inf_{j \ge k} f_j(n)$$

I am not sure that equation true. Is that equation true? Then why is it?

Comment: Why don't you specify what are those objects you're working with?

Comment: I just wanna solve http://math.stackexchange.com/q/142728/30883 problem. But I have no basic knowledge wanna have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known that for any sequence $\{a_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\liminf\limits_{k\to\infty}a_k=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\inf\limits_{j\geq k}a_j
$$
so
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\liminf\limits_{k\to\infty}f_k(n)=
\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\inf\limits_{j\geq k}f_j(n)=
\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\inf\limits_{j\geq k}f_j(n)
$$

Comment: Oh thanks. Is last equation undoubtfully true?(switching sum and limit)

Comment: It is true, because sum is finite and doesn't depend on limit's variable.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks @norbert!

Comment: @japee Not at all!

Comment: @japee By the way, you can accept this answer and answers for other your questions - click grey checkmark under two vertical arrows

Comment: Ah I clicked and it change to green button. I got it!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3373/discussion-between-japee-and-norbert)

Comment: Sure! I accepted other three now. I got scholar badge indeed. Thanks!